# How to remove top cell separator line

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How do I get rid of the separator line appearing above the status bar? It's hard to see in a screenshot, so I colored it red. I tried the code below for the first cell, but that didn't work.

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.0f);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

In `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` return a view with zero rect i.e `[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`

In `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` return height as 0.01.

Mind section if you have multiple sections in table view.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. My tableview is Grouped, but I'd like to keep it that way. Just want to remove this annoying line at the top.